# VB Studio ListBox scrollbar position

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Perhaps there's a better solution, but...

I am using a `listbox` to select multiple items, but the list contains 800+ items in alphabetical order.  If I am selecting three items, for example, "Apples", "Oranges" and "Zucchini", I have to pull the `scrollbar` down or use the mouse wheel to scroll through the list.

Is there any way to "jump" to a location in the list to reduce the scrolling needed?  For example, if I had a `button` for "D", the scroll list would jump down to the items starting with "D".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly use the event handler for KeyDown within the ListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you need.

The second line searches through the listbox to find the first item that begins with the key you pressed. If no Items begin with that letter, the FindString function returns -1 or the same as ListBox.NoMatches ( which is a constant already defined in Visual Studio to make code more readable)

I've put the code into a separate sub so that it can be resused to apply to any listbox.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyDown
    Dim key As String = Chr(e.KeyValue).ToString
    SelectlistBoxItemFromKey(ListBox1, key)
End Sub

Private Sub SelectlistBoxItemFromKey(ByRef lBox As ListBox, k As String)
    Dim index As Integer = lBox.FindString(k)
    If index > ListBox.NoMatches Then
        lBox.SelectedIndex = index - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the answer works for you don't forget to tick it as accepted so that other users looking for the same solution will see that it works - and also to help incentivize people who do the answering ;-)

Comment: And - No problem glad to help.